# JButton action in other class

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a main Frame with two panels:

```
JPanel Menu = new Menu();
Menu.setBounds(0, 37, 300, 644);
contentPane.add(Menu);
Menu.setVisible(false);

JPanel Fahrtenbearbeiten = new Fahrtenbearbeiten();
Fahrtenbearbeiten.setBounds(0, 0, 1422, 668);
contentPane.add(Fahrtenbearbeiten);
```

In the Menu panel, I want to make a button, who sets the `Fahrtenbearbeiten` panel's `Visible(false)`. The Problem is: How can I reach an action which is triggered in the Menu panel (`Menu.java`) and has an action in an other file (`Haupt.java`)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should have a look into the MVC paradigm. It is not healthy to code the behaviour directly in the components; better send a message and react in a controller object.

Comment: Do you know how to make an action on the button in this class? If so, show how you would do it. If not, go back to the docs. Because there is no real difference in making the action come from one class or another.

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable names should begin with a lower case character to differentiate them from class names, so it would be better if you do `JPanel fahrtenbearbeiten = new Fahrtenbearbeiten();` instead of `JPanel Fahrtenbearbeiten = new Fahrtenbearbeiten();`, the same holds for `JPanel Menu = new Menu();` which should be `JPanel menu = new Menu();`. Also one usually writes code in english, is also more easy for people at SO to help you if they can understand the code.

Comment: @Zabuza while your advice is good and OP should definitely stick to Java conventions, I don't think that the omission is going to prevent anyone with the ability to answer this question from answering. Also, it is perfectly normal to name variables in the local language when not in 'Murica.

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare the `Fahrtenbearbeiten` JPanel as global variable

   ```
   private JPanel fahrtenbearbeitenPnl = new JPanel();
   ```
2. Create a method

   ```
   public void hideFahrtenbearbeitenPnl()
   {
      fahrtenbearbeitenPnl.setVisible(false);
   }
   ```
3. Call this method on the object of the class which contains the panel. For example:

   ```
   menu.hideFahrtenbearbeitenPnl();
   ```

Let me know if I've got your question wrong. (Maybe post the whole class(es) for easier support)